# Create a Hibernate Predicate for comparing two dates

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to build a predicate that will retrieve a dueDate and compare it to today. Obviously the code below doesn't work. I am uncertain how to compare dates as Hibernate predicates. Help is appreciated.

```
Date currentDate = new Date();

Expression<Boolean> dueDateExp = trainingEntryRoot.get("dueDate");
Expression<Boolean> currentDateExp = currentDate;
Predicate dueDatePred = builder.greaterThan(dueDateExp, currentDate);
```

Comment: If it is not clear greaterThan() expression doesn't work for date types. I need something that can compare dates or convert them to something that can be compared.